# want to fix a div after scrolling of a page upto a particular position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner to the UI ,so I need a sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Check out:

[changing an elements css position after scrolling down the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907872/changing-an-elements-css-position-after-scrolling-down-the-page)

Replace the *ul* stuff with whatever your div's name is and the *fixed* stuff with whatever your classes name is for the div when it's scrolled (and supposed to be fixed).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by css also...use `position:absolute`