# changing an elements css position after scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am messing around with some jquery trying to get to grips with it.

I have a ul nav which has a absolute position set but after I scroll the page down by 200 pixels i would like that to switch to position fixed so that the nav always stays on the page.

How would I do this?

below is the example I am working on

http://satbulsara.com/tests/

Comment: why not use by default the `position:fixed`?

Comment: Set the poition to "fixed" instead of "absolute".

Comment: ok but I would like the nav to scroll down to a point and then switch to fixed after, how can I get jquery to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for being so quick to help

this is what i wanted

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theLoc = $('ul').position().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if(theLoc >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            if($('ul').hasClass('fixed')) {
                $('ul').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        } else { 
            if(!$('ul').hasClass('fixed')) {
                $('ul').addClass('fixed');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/cheald/floatingFixed/blob/master/jquery.floatingFixed.js) to do just that.

Comment: Neat! I'll definitely look at using that in my next projects, if I may :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I use to create a "sticky" sidebar. You'll need to modify the IDs to suit your markup.

```
var sidebarScrollTop = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    sidebarScrollTop = $("#sidebar").offset();

    $(window).scroll(function () { 
        var docScrollTop = $('body,html').scrollTop();

        if(docScrollTop > sidebarScrollTop.top) {
            $("#sidebar").css({ position: 'fixed', top: '0px' });
        } else {
            $("#sidebar").css({ position: 'static' });
        }
    });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    sidebarScrollTop = $("#sidebar").offset().top;
});

$(document).resize(function() {
    sidebarScrollTop = $("#sidebar").offset().top;
});
```

Basically, all you need to do is change the `#sidebar` for the ID of the sidebar container. This code will see if the sidebar element is scrolled past the top of the screen. If it is, it changes it's position to `fixed`, and when it returns to being on the page again, the position is returned to `static` (default).

The `$(document).resize()` and `$(window).resize()` functions will make sure the sidebar stays stick at the top of the page when the document/window is resized respectively. The document function will ensure the sidebar works properly even if you have jQuery animations changing the size of elements.

Comment: Thanks James thats almost what I am looking for, i would like to be able to scroll the nav up a bit and then have it stick + this one seems to flash when i scroll up and down

Comment: thanks james for pointing me in the right way but this is what i was looking for exactly

Comment: @sat - I use it on a site I'm developing and it works fine. If it flickers, maybe try putting the sidebar inside a `div` container.