# How to switch fixed elements when scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

How do people switch fixed elements when scrolling down the page? Here's a perfect example of what I mean at `www.Joel.is`.  If you look at the share buttons, as you scroll down past one post, the share button of the next post replaces the previous one using `position:fixed`

I have only seen posts that answer how to create the initial fixed position, but not switching. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907872/changing-an-elements-css-position-after-scrolling-down-the-page).

Comment: Ever heard of "View Source..."?

Comment: Did that already. Still not sure...js scripts are jumbled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the same principles, but edit the style of the element.

```
<div style="position: static;" id="ele"></div>
```

and then:

```
document.getElementById('ele').style.position = "absolute";
```

or for jQuery:

```
$('#ele').css('position', 'absolute');
```