# position fixed the first row of my table when it reaching the top of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is it posible to have the first row of the table to position:fixed when it reaching the top of the browser so that when you scroll further down you still see the names?
this is the page of the website where i want to do this:
http://all-areas-bikers.be/klassement

my html is:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:750px" >
<div id="positionFix">
<table class="klassement">
<tbody>
<tr class="leden">
<td class="datum">Datum</td>
<td>Bart</td>
<td>Benny</td>
<td>Marijn</td>
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Pieter</td>
<td>Steven Ds</td>
<td>Steven Sp</td>
<td>Sven</td>
<td>Wim</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<table class="klassement">
<tbody>
<tr class="leden nocolor">
<td class="datum">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">2 feb 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">9 feb 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">16 feb 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">&nbsp;23 feb 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">2 ma 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">9 ma 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">16 ma 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">&nbsp;23 ma 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">30 ma 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">6 apr 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="datum">13 apr 2014</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I have read a lot of other question which are almost the same but canot come trough the solution. The table will be getting longer as the year goes by.

My javascript is not that good so please can someone help me with this. It is a joomla site, so i don't know if its posible.

Benny

Comment: You can `position:fixed` the entire table when it reaches a certain height, but all of the elements of the table are together.  If you can make the table scrollable by itself, then it might be easy to do that.  Otherwise, you will have to make the first row of the table as a different element, then you can fix that element while the table scrolls

Comment: hi, thanx for the fast reply. i updated my html, is this better to try with?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
table tr:first-child {
position:fixed;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxn72/

Ok, to give you an idea of what you have to do:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 var row = $('table tr:first-child');
     rowOff = row.offset();   
 if (rowOff.top < 10) {
  row.css({position:fixed, top:0});
});
```

I made it `< 10` because you have to fiddle a bit around with when the browser sending the actual number...

Comment: no that does not do the trick. i also tried that but it fixes on that place and not when it comes on the top of your browser. When i scroll down the first row would go into my footer.

Comment: @BennyVanDenHeuvel Can you do a fiddle with all your stuff?

Answer (score 0):

I found a piece of code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907872/changing-an-elements-css-position-after-scrolling-down-the-page):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var theLoc = $('ul').position().top;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if(theLoc >= $(window).scrollTop()) {
            if($('ul').hasClass('fixed')) {
                $('ul').removeClass('fixed');
            }
        } else { 
            if(!$('ul').hasClass('fixed')) {
                $('ul').addClass('fixed');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I'm guessing that you should replace the 'ul' part in this code with your class 'leden', and make sure that the class that is added contains the necessary positioning.

Comment: thanx for this tip. when i tried this in jsfiddle it seems to do something not totaly good but it looks like it. when i use it in my (joomla) website it does nothing. You can see the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gxn72/33/ and the website view you can see here:

Comment: Now after i changed a litle in my html, css and the script like above it is working fine for me. Thank you Avisari!!!